# Partitioning an arraylist into Map buckets

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have two ArrayLists of type String `ArrayList<String> xList` and `ArrayList<String> yList` and I want to partition one list into buckets, according to someAttribute (for the below example lets say it uses .contains().

```
   Map<String, List<String>> yBuckets = new HashMap<>();
             yList.forEach(y -> yBuckets.compute(y.contains("I'm here"), (k,v) ->
                     (v == null ? new ArrayList<>() : v).add(y)));
```

However I'm getting an incompatible types error (String can't be converted to Boolean). I've never really used Java 8 to date but it seems to be useful for what I want so I'm wondering if anyone would be able to tell me how i'd go about fixing this code.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide an example in terms of the input and output data?

Comment: `Map.compute` takes key as first parameter. In your case it will be a `String` but `y.contains` returns boolean.

Comment: "into buckets". Well, values come up from `yList`, what keys do these values have in a map?

Comment: it's all good giving code examples but it would really help if you also gave an example input and the expected result to better illustrate your description.

Comment: there are a couple of questions about your question... first why do you say you have two lists when you only care about one? then your example will "partition" in two logical parts only - `false` : List and `true` : `List` as such there is a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use lambda, you could use one of the toMap Collectors:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-

For Example, partitioning a list of names into buckets by last name:

```
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Steve Ray", "Bobby Ray", "Billy Bob", "Timmy Bob");
    Map<String, List<String>> nameBuckets = names.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(str -> {return str.split(" ")[1];}, Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 1):

For the example that you provided there is `Collectors.partitioningBy` but this will partition in `two` parts only - based on a `Predicate`.

```
yList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(y -> y.contains("I'm here")));
```

As such that is going to be a result in the form of `Map<Boolean, List<String>>`.

If you have more groups, you would want to use `Collectors.groupingBy` that will `partition` your List base on a `Function`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 mistakes in your code. The first one is that if you want to partition based on `.contains` which returns a `boolean` your map needs to be `Map<Boolean, List<String>>`.

The second mistake is with parenthesis. The `(k,v) ->...` lambda needs to return `List<String>` because you put `.add(y)` inside the lambda it return a `boolean` you need to add to the list returned by `compute` like so:

```
yList.forEach(y -> yBuckets.compute(y.contains("I'm here"), (k,v) ->
(v == null ? new ArrayList<>() : v)).add(y));
```

Comment: that wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Aominè That's copied straight from a running program so your claim is false.

Comment: @Aominè It compiles and runs correctly, whatever you see you see it wrong.

Comment: @Aominè Not if you change the map key to `Boolean` if OP wants to partition based on `.contains` then the key must be a boolean as I said at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: whether that's what OP wants I don't know but OP is using a String as a key for their current example. the question may need clarification but just wanted to point it out.

Comment: And he also partitions based on `.contains` one of those things needs to be changed.